# I want to add a color to the highest number in the column row on the table

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

**Original Version**
[image]

**What I expect**
[image]

I need to do my table like this but I don't know JavaScript and I need some help about that.

Numbers are always changing

They said it could be done with JavaScript or PHP, but I couldn't do it with php. Since I have no knowledge of JavaScript, I wanted to consult you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="tr-TR">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="custom-table-responsive ">
        <div class="text-center">
          <div class="bg-light p-3 overflow-hidden rounded border shadow">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-light mb-0 table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th style="width: 220px" rowspan="2" class="align-middle">
                      <div>TESTER</div>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="2">
                      <div><a href="#" class="hide-row float-right"></a>Category 1</div>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="2">
                      <div><a href="#" class="hide-row float-right"></a>Category 2</div>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="2">
                      <div><a href="#" class="hide-row float-right"></a>Category 3</div>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="2">
                      <div><a href="#" class="hide-row float-right"></a>Category 4</div>
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th><span>Sell</span></th>
                    <th><span>Buy</span></th>
                    <th><span>Sell</span></th>
                    <th><span>Buy</span></th>
                    <th><span>Sell</span></th>
                    <th><span>Buy</span></th>
                    <th><span>Sell</span></th>
                    <th><span>Buy</span></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="table-left-seperator">TEST</th>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="table-left-seperator">TEST</th>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="table-left-seperator">TEST</th>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="table-left-seperator">TEST</th>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo rand(100,1500); ?></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if this data is known on the server side there and determine the extremes. for them, when generating html, you can insert inline css defining color. There is no reason to load client devices.

Comment: Seems like if you could not do it in PHP you did not attack it right. You want to generate the numbers all first and then loop over them. You do not want to hard code everything like you did.

Comment: I don't quite get the logic. In Category 2 - sell column, the green number is the highest, but all other sell columns they are the lowest?

Comment: @Bqardi sorry i marked it wrong :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While SO isn't the place for getting people to do code for you, this was a fun challenge, so I couldn't help myself, sorry.

I agree that this should be done serverside for convenience (and maybe even for performance(?)), but here is a Javascript solution.

I hardcoded the random `php` values, but you can just replace all numbers again with `<?php echo rand(100,1500); ?>` or use your own (it will still work with your original `php`/`html`).

```js
const tBody = document.querySelector("tbody");
const trs = tBody.querySelectorAll("tr");
const tds = tBody.querySelectorAll("td");

const numberOfColumns = tds.length / trs.length;
let isSellClm = true;

for (let clm = 0; clm < numberOfColumns; clm++) {
  const highLow = {
    value: isSellClm ? Infinity : 0,
    element: null
  };

  for (let row = 0; row < trs.length; row++) {
    const td = tds[row * numberOfColumns + clm];
    const number = parseInt(td.textContent);

    if (isSellClm) {
      if (number < highLow.value) {
        highLow.value = number,
          highLow.element = td;
      }
    } else {
      if (number > highLow.value) {
        highLow.value = number,
          highLow.element = td;
      }
    }
  }

  highLow.element.style.color = isSellClm ? "green" : "red";
  isSellClm = !isSellClm;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-table-responsive ">
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="bg-light p-3 overflow-hidden rounded border shadow">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-light mb-0 table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width: 220px" rowspan="2" class="align-middle">
                  <div>TESTER</div>
                </th>
                <th colspan="2">
                  <div>
                    <a href="#" class="hide-row float-right"></a>Category 1</div>
                </th>
                <th colspan="2">
                  <div>
                    <a href="#" class="hide-row float-right"></a>Category 2</div>
                </th>
                <th colspan="2">
                  <div>
                    <a href="#" class="hide-row float-right"></a>Category 3</div>
                </th>
                <th colspan="2">
                  <div>
                    <a href="#" class="hide-row float-right"></a>Category 4</div>
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th><span>Sell</span></th>
                <th><span>Buy</span></th>
                <th><span>Sell</span></th>
                <th><span>Buy</span></th>
                <th><span>Sell</span></th>
                <th><span>Buy</span></th>
                <th><span>Sell</span></th>
                <th><span>Buy</span></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th class="table-left-seperator">TEST</th>
                <td>398</td>
                <td>510</td>
                <td>359</td>
                <td>809</td>
                <td>1151</td>
                <td>1123</td>
                <td>787</td>
                <td>1443</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="table-left-seperator">TEST</th>
                <td>549</td>
                <td>1201</td>
                <td>1112</td>
                <td>1276</td>
                <td>1440</td>
                <td>177</td>
                <td>822</td>
                <td>218</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="table-left-seperator">TEST</th>
                <td>1278</td>
                <td>701</td>
                <td>797</td>
                <td>194</td>
                <td>403</td>
                <td>477</td>
                <td>1447</td>
                <td>534</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="table-left-seperator">TEST</th>
                <td>712</td>
                <td>1399</td>
                <td>406</td>
                <td>411</td>
                <td>531</td>
                <td>497</td>
                <td>483</td>
                <td>459</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If you need the code to be more robust, you should give the queried elements an `id` or `data-attribute` or some other unique identifier and query that, eg.:

```html
<tbody id="table-body">
```

```js
const tBody = document.querySelector("#table-body");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me and sorry for not knowing, I just wanted to ask here for help. It creates a problem when the data is float. How can I fix this if I am not too burdensome for you, is it possible for you to answer this?

Comment: There is also a `parseFloat()` function for float numbers.